# What is the slowest long haul commercial aircraft in service to this day?

Tags: commercial-aviation, long-haul

I have been looking at planes used in routes for airlines to see which model was the slowest.But I still don’t know which aircraft is the slowest.

Edit: long haul meaning: SFO-HND
Also, only passenger.

(Sorry if the question was confusing. It’s my first time asking a question on here)

Comment: What is it you're hoping to gain by knowing this information? There may be a better question to ask that will get you closer to what you _really_ want.

Comment: It might be best to speak to a travel agent.  SFO-HND seems to be trans Pacific from San Francisco to Tokyo.  These days most likely jets, unless the [Clipper 314](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_314_Clipper) is still around.

Comment: @Leo Are you asking about any long haul route, or only about SFO-HND?

Comment: I just noticed this in the question title, "in service _to this day_". "to this day" means, to me, since the inception of commercial flight. That means that a plane like the DC-3 (cruise speed 180kn) is significantly slower than any of the answers proposed so far, even the Clipper 314 suggested by @RobertDiGiovanni. I don't _think_ this is what the OP is after, but since he hasn't come back to clarify, then the DC3 is my suggestion. I'm sure there are earlier commercial aircraft with slower speeds.

Comment: ... especially since the DC3 is in service _to this day_. Probably can't make the SFO-HND crossing, though, at least non-stop.

Comment: Not just SFO-HND. I meant routes like that.

Comment: The clipper was retire a long time ago by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A330 has a top speed of 489 knots according to the dubiously accurate [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=A330).  I do not have a complete list of long haul commercial aircraft, but that might be the slowest of the common ones.

The IL-62, which is allegedly still flying commercially, goes 490 knots according to Wikipedia.